# How to store sensitive user data for webservers

Tags: database, security, encryption

Is there any way to store sensitive user data in database such that even if the server and db are compromised the attacker cannot read the original data? You can obviously encrypt the data but then the keys have to be accessible by the server for decryption, and would be compromised along with the server.

EDIT: i'll be using vps hosting such as linode. Assume attacker can gain root access to the server (which also has the database and source code) for an hour.

Comment: How you protect data against an attacker compromising your system depends heavily on how you expect to be attacked and/or compromised. Different threat profiles require different preventative measures.  There aren't any silver bullet answers to the general problem, only to specific ones.

Comment: Under your attack model, this is obviously impossible.

Answer (score 3):

**Get Keys from an Admin User**

Only store the keys in memory in the server. The memory only copies are used to decrypt data as it is needed. When the server starts up it has to get the key information from the administrator. There are variations on this, of course. The administrator could plug in a USB drive for just that moment. The admin could provide a password providing momentary access to another machine where the keys are in a database or whatever. The admin could type in the password for the keystore file which would be on the server in response to a prompt on the console. The web site wouldn't work until the admin logs in and chooses the "Enter keys" option.

This makes it so the attacker has to find the keys in memory before they can decrypt the data.

**Keys on a 2nd Machine**

There is a 2nd method used that is less secure than relying on the admin but still somewhat safer. Put the keys on a 2nd machine somewhere on the network. Make sure it doesn't have the same user accounts as the server. When the server starts up, it has to connect to the other machine somehow and get the keys, storing them only in memory. You could, again, rely on the admin to provide the password to an account on the other machine or, in Linux, use SCP with a stored key. It is important to make the communications secure so the attacker can't just see the keys as they cross the network.

In this case the attacker has to compromise two machines to get the data from one and the keys from another. So it is safer than having keys on the same machine.

**Other Points**

You can find all this and more on the web. Google is your friend.

But remember some obvious security precautions to make it harder for the bad guys:

1. Physically secure the system. Don't let the bad guys get their hands on the keyboard.
2. Use an OS with good security features and make use of those features.
3. Disable the root password and require all users to log in via their identifiable account and then do something to gain root privileges if needed. (Then keep a log of all logins and access to root so you can tell who did what.)
4. Monitor what is going on on the machine. This may mean video surveillance or just checking out the logs.
5. Keep backup "tapes" secure. They contain the same secrets as the disk drives.
6. Don't leave memory dumps lying around where they could give up their secrets.
7. Consider the people who do have access. Are they reliable? Can they be bribed? Can you check on their actions? Are they low paid or disgruntled?

Comment: I like the idea of keeping the keys in memory. +1 for that!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a key fob / USB to hold the relevant encryption data but typically if physical security is compromised, all bets are off.

Comment: This provides no protection against an attacker who compromises the live running system.